# adding tr tag causes function to stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function below which works correctly:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   
    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $noofanswers = $("<td class='noofanswers'></td>");
    var $questionType = '';

    $('.numberAnswerTxt', context).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $noofanswersText = '';

        if ($questionType == 'True or False' || $questionType == 'Yes or No') {
            $noofanswersText = $("<span class='naRow string' style='display: block;'>Only 1 Answer</span><input type='text' class='numberAnswerTxtRow answertxt' style='display: none;' onkeyup='numberKeyUp(this)' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onChange='getButtons()'>").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val());
        }
        else {
            $noofanswersText = $("<span class='naRow string' style='display: none;'>Only 1 Answer</span><input type='text' class='numberAnswerTxtRow answertxt' style='display: block;' onkeyup='numberKeyUp(this)' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' onChange='getButtons()'>").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val());  
        }

        $noofanswers.append($noofanswersText);
    }); 

    $tr.append($noofanswers);
    $tbody.append($tr); 
}
```

But I wanted `$noofanswers` to be included in it's own table row so I then change `$noofanswers` to include `<tr></tr>` so that code:

```
var $noofanswers = $("<td class='noofanswers'></td>");
```

now becomes:

```
var $noofanswers = $("<tr><td class='noofanswers'></td></tr>");
```

But if I do this then `$('.numberAnswerTxt', context).each(function() {` doesn't quite work correctly. So my question is that if I add the `<tr>` tags, then what do I need to change within the function to get it working again?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I should of mentioned that this isn't the only piece of code where I have included `tr` tags, there are some other code as well which I have now included in question. I have tried both answers but problem is that it messes up the look of it because so colums have extra `tr` tags and some don't.

Answer (score 1):

The `insertQuestion` function already wraps the `td` element in a `tr`:

```
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
//...
$tr.append($noofanswers);
```

You could simply modify `$tr` instead of adding the `tr` to `$noofanswers`, or you could remove the call to `append` and keep the `tr` in `$noofanswers`.

```
//var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
var $noofanswers = $("<tr><td class='noofanswers'></td></tr>");
//...
//$tr.append($noofanswers);
$tbody.append($noofanswers);
```

Comment: I have eddited question and include comment on top. I can't simply just do what you have stated because I have multiple columns, I tried to post one example of code in question but as you though this was only column, I had to include all the columns I am appending.

Comment: Also found out doing it this way also means functions don't work also

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
var $noofanswers = $("<td class='noofanswers'></td>");
```

and later

```
$tr.append($noofanswers);
$tbody.append($tr);
```

so you cannot wrap your `td` by another `tr` since it's already wrapped. Then you should change your code like so:

```
var $noofanswers = $("<tr><td class='noofanswers'></td></tr>");
...
$tbody.append($noofanswers);
```

Comment: Look at comment below question